# Rights of the commander of the Military Unit?

Tags: erepublik

What are the rights of the commander of a military unit in and how is it different from regiment captain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

commander can appoint 2nd commander...
he can remove any member from any regiment...
he can transfer his commandership to anyone...

Captain..
Captain gets elected through voting in his own regiment on 15th of every month
captain can invite any member from any regiment to his own regiment..
he can kick member from his own regiment only

commander can set or change orders 5 times a day only... Commander can set the priority of country in which in the absence of commander the Daily Order sets automatically depending on the priority battle going on... Commander can set the membership criteria for new members to become "FULL MEMBER"

Captain can just set daily oder 5 times a day...

Answer (score 2):

1. The preference for battle order displayed on the home page is given to the captain then the commander. While doing both the orders counts towards the daily BO. Only the captain's order is displayed unless no DO is set by the captain, in this case the DO set by the commander is displayed in home page.
2. Commander can edit the Description of the MU, change the logo of the MU and the name of the MU, which a Captain can't.
3. The commander's shout in the MU feed has the name of the MU displayed instead of the name of the commander. The shout as such is displayed on top of all the shouts.